# How to stop planes from changing colours in the arcore sample project from google

Tags: android, arcore

I have downloaded the sample ARCore project using JAVA and OPENGL. I have gone thru the code, and I can't find out why the planes are changing colours. Is this a default thing. How do I disable it?

Answer (score 3):

It happens when setting the shader variables in [PlaneRenderer.java](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/java_arcore_hello_ar/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/core/examples/java/helloar/rendering/PlaneRenderer.java#L376):

```
int colorIndex = planeIndex % PLANE_COLORS_RGBA.length;
colorRgbaToFloat(mPlaneColor, PLANE_COLORS_RGBA[colorIndex]);
GLES20.glUniform4fv(mLineColorUniform, 1, mPlaneColor, 0);
GLES20.glUniform4fv(mDotColorUniform, 1, mPlaneColor, 0);
```

So the easiest/quickest modification would be to set the color index to a constant value